# Passing an array through a function's parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters

I'm trying to simplify something like this using multiple variables such as "one_a", "one_b" and so on.:

```
$(".one_a").mouseover(function(){
    $('.main_box').addClass("one_a");
    });
    $(".one_a").mouseout(function(){
     $('.main_box').removeClass("one_a");
});
```

This is what I have so far, I'm having trouble returning a variable from the "runShapes" function and passing it through the "swapBackground" function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var myShapes=new Array();
    myShapes[0]="one_a";      
    myShapes[1]="one_b";
    myShapes[2]="one_c";

function runShapes(){
    for (var i=0;i<myShapes.length;i++){
    }
    return myShapes[i];
}

function swapBackground(currentShape){
    $(currentShape).mouseover(function(){
        $('.main_box').addClass(currentShape);
    });
    $(currentShape).mouseout(function(){
        $('.main_box').removeClass(currentShape);
    });
}

window.onload = swapBackground("." + runShapes);
```

Comment: <s>Do not install a `mouseout` handler every time the `mouseover` handler is invoked!</s> Indent your code properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm having trouble returning a variable from the "runShapes" function and passing it through the "swapBackground" function.

You should not return it. You should just call the `swapBackground` function from `runShapes` like this:

```
function runShapes(){
    for (var i=0;i<myShapes.length;i++){
         swapBackground(myShapes[i]); // don't add the dot here, you won't need
                                      // it for add/removeClass
    }
}
```

Then, invoke `runShapes` when the [document is ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) - do not use `window.onload`:

```
$(document).ready(runShapes);
```

Btw, you better might use [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to install your handlers:

```
function swapBackground(currentShape) {
    $("." + currentShape).hover(function(){
        $('.main_box').addClass(currentShape);
    }, function(){
        $('.main_box').removeClass(currentShape);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.each` like this :

```
$.each(["one_a", "one_b", "one_c"], function(_,shape) {
    $('.'+shape).mouseover(function(){
        $('.main_box').addClass(shape);
    }).mouseout(function(){
       $('.main_box').removeClass(shape);
    });
});
```

Note that I changed your code so that the `mouseout` event is only bound once. You might also be interested in the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function.